# Uniqueness of inverses in rings.

Tags: ring-theory

I can't get example of ring where inverses aren't unique ? What is condition required for the inverses to be unique .
Kindly help..

Comment: In a ring with identity, if an inverse exists, it is unique. It's pretty much the same proof as for groups...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any binary operation that is associative and has an identity element, if a left and a right inverse for an element exist, they are necessarily equal.

Indeed, suppose that $ax=e$, $xb=e$. Then
$$
a=ae=axb=eb=b.
$$
A particular consequence is that inverses are unique in any context where the operation is associative.

Comment: I have a doubt that : we can't define inverses if identity element doesn't exists ,because definition of inverse of an element $a$ says that it is that element $b$ s.t. $ab=$ identity . for this we require identity to exist ...

Comment: Yes, that's the point. If there is no identity, the question is meaningless.